# Compare Date in python

Tags: python, date

i'm trying to compare 2 date in python, a date from a dataframe and a date that i will increase of 7 days every cicle. With the target to add in the dataframe the missing date.

```
ky = ResearchFrame['Order Date'].loc[ResearchFrame['Order Date'] == ResearchFrame['Order Date'].min()]
```

I'm using ky that is minimum date of the dataframe and then i will add 7 days.

```
for i in ResearchFrame['Order Date']:
 if ky != i:
    ResearchFrame['Order Date'] = ky
    ResearchFrame['Quantity'] = 0
 ky += datetime.timedelta(days=7)
```

This is the error that i recive:
"The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: What line is the error message happening on - please edit the full error message into your question

Comment: in this line if ky != i:

Comment: add a line`print( "i,k=",i,k)` before that line - what does it show?

Comment: i,k= 2016-01-09 00:00:00 194   2016-01-09
Name: Order Date, dtype: datetime64[ns].

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the error must be on the line: `if ky != i`

Check your variables but one of them (`ky` or `i`) should be a `Serie` and not a single date value. Hence, comparison may return a `Serie` as well, and it is not allowed to use a serie as a condition value. You should instead check that the serie is either `empty`, that `any` or `all` values are `True`, etc.

As mentionned in the comment, provide a minimal running example and the full stack trace when asking a question.

### Edit

As shown in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58588481/compare-date-in-python/58588609#comment103490493_58588481), the `k` value is indeed a `Serie` of a single value. Either convert it to a scalar, or use the `any` or `all` functions for the comparison:

```
if (k != i).all():
  ...
```